# Calculate renewal transactions

Tags: powerpivot, dax

A slight variation on some other questions I've seen posted where people are trying to calculate a renewal date.  I'm trying to create a formula that counts transactions that are up for renewal in a given time period based on a 'TO DATE' I already have on each transaction.  Just a little stuck coming up with something that takes a 'distinct transaction' and a 'to date' date column and yields a measure that counts the transactions up for renewal based on that date.

Happy to provide more information if need be.

Comment: Put a date table in your model and create a relationship from your [To Date] to the date in the date table. On your transaction table, create a calculated measure that is a count distinct of your transaction ID.

Comment: sample data to share would be helpful :)